Exception RISCV APB
I have a RISC-V core receiving commands from an APB3 interface, and I would like to test the pslverr flag. I noticed that the core hangs when pslverr is received so I probably need to handle it properly. Can somebody help me on this? Where should I start looking at?
Thanks,
Stefano
